# TeXshop Won't Compile My Indices

Tags: indexing

I am using `multind`.  I am typing a large set of notes.  I want to have two indices, one called "Index" the other "Notation".  The `.idx` files exist for both of them after compiling.  My problem is that I don't know how to run a `makeindex` for each of the indices.  This is my first time using TeXshop.  When I run `makeindex` it searches for a `.idx` file that has the filename the same as the notes I am typing.  How do I get `makeindex` run on `notation.idx` and `index.idx`?  Better yet, is there a way of setting up a command that runs `LaTeX`, then `makeindex` for each index, then `LaTeX` again?

EDIT: I have changed to `imakeidx`.  My preamble has in it:

```
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex{index}
\makeindex{notation}
```

and at the end of the files I have

```
\printindex{notation}{Notation}
\printindex{index}{Index}
```

I no longer call the package multind or makeindex.

Comment: Did you try `imakeidx` instead of `multind`?

Comment: @egreg I have tried.  My edit explains some more.

Comment: The syntax of `imakeidx` is slightly different from `multind`.

Comment: @egreg I have figured out how to make imakeidx work without splitindex.  What a wonderful package.  But, when I add splitindex as an option the indices disappear.  Is splitindex necessary?

Comment: No, `splitindex` is not necessary; it's there as a safety measure because the number of write streams is limited. With just two indices hitting the limit is unlikely.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the help.  If you wish to list your comments as an answer, I will gladly accept.